# Mock Typed HttpClient in Integration Tests with .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am looking for some ideas for mocking Typed HttpClient in integration tests in an Asp.net core application.

Let's say I have a service collection with a registered Typed HttpClient like this

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<ITestApiClient, TestApiClient>();

var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

and `TestApiClient` definition like this

```
public class TestApiClient: ITestApiClient
{
    HttpClient _httpClient;
    public TestApiClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void MakeTestApiCall()
    {
        var response = _httpClient.GetAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
        response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Dump();
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to inject a mock `HttpClient` implementation into `TestApiClient` using ServiceCollection without directly instantiating `TestApiClient`.

Similar to how we can do below in the integration tests to replace a real Foo implementation with mocked Foo implementation.

```
var fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
services.AddSingleton(fooMock);
```

Please note, I already figured a way to mock HttpClient with Moq and libraries like `RichardSzalay.MockHttp`. My question is how to replace the typed Httpclient within the ServiceCollection (Mocking HttpClientFactory?).

Comment: May be have a look at Inversion of Control (IoC) e.g. https://autofac.org/

Comment: @DanielW. Can you elaborate? Does Autofac offer something in this regards that Microsoft's DI framework doesn't?

Comment: Not really a good list of IoC tools is https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2019/01/24/the-ultimate-list-of-net-dependency-injection-frameworks/

Comment: @DanielW. Not sure if you understood my question correctly. I am aware of IoC and simply using a different IoC framework is not a solution. I would appreciate if you could offer a more specific solution.

Comment: Could you eleborate on why you want to mock `HttpClient`? I mean, why do you specifically want to use the `ServiceCollection`/DI? Can't you just make the address point to a local in some environment variable, which differs for testing? P.s. `.Result` is not the proper way to use async... you should await the calls

Comment: @JHBonarius That is just some test code to show what I was trying to ask. I agree that .Result should be not used.
 Yeah, I can change the address to a localhost url and use a library like WireMock to run a mock http server. However, I would like to make use of WebApplicationFactory pattern recommended by microsoft and keep the code clean and reusable. If I would like to mock multiple Http Services, then wiremock code becomes kind of messy.

Comment: Does [this](https://gist.github.com/DavidPx/f0921e17e58e5ebe33d526b8430e93da) help? _"...As you might know HttpClient is not mockable so you have to provide a mocked HttpMessageHandler...."_

Comment: @JHBonarius Thanks for trying to help. Yeah, that gist is trying to solve the same problem as mine. I actually found a way to mock HttpClient (well the HttpMessageHandler). The problem is with injecting that into DI container. The gist looks incomplete. If you notice, they are passing `additionalRegistrations` parameter to `RegisterDependencies` function, but not using it. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @user7368874 have you found a way to this? having the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the issue of mocking an HttpClient in aspnet core 6 integration tests :

I created a custom WebApplicationFactory for the integration tests where I replace the HttpClient service by an new client using a mocked HttpMessageHandler.

```cs
internal class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    public Mock<HttpMessageHandler> handlerMock { get; private set; }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Remove existing IHttpClientFactory and HttpClient
            var httpClientFactoryDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType ==
                    typeof(IHttpClientFactory));
            services.Remove(httpClientFactoryDescriptor);

            var httpClientDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType ==
                    typeof(HttpClient));
            services.Remove(httpClientDescriptor);

            // Create a mock HttpMessageHandler
            this.handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

            // Create an HttpClient using the mocked handler
            var client = new HttpClient(this.handlerMock.Object);
            var clientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
            clientFactoryMock
                .Setup(f => f.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(client);

            // Add the new HttpClient as singleton
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(clientFactoryMock.Object);
            services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(client);
        });
    }
}
```

The mocked HttpMessageHandler is exposed as a public property to be accessible by the test class where I can do the setup :

```cs
    [Fact]
    public async Task CallApiTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory();
        var client = factory.CreateClient();

        factory.handlerMock
               .Protected()
               .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                   "SendAsync",
                   ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(r => r.Method == HttpMethod.Get),
                   ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
               .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
               { 
                   StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                   Content = new StringContent("[]") 
               });

        // Act
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/callApi");

        // Assert
        result.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```